# Cache my previously created objects

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I have scenario like this. I have a method called `createObject` like this:

```
public MyInterface createObject(EnumData data){
 //creates many objects of the classes implements MyInterface interface
 switch(data)
 {
     case AppObject:
         return new AppObject();
     case TestObject:
         return new TestObject();
 }
}
```

I wish I want to cache these objects. Because the method `createObject` called many times, I wish the objects shouldn't be created every time, rather re-use already created objects.

#### Note:

I'm not looking for Singleton here, as that wont suit my use case. Instead since this method is creating alots of objects, I want only this method to re-use them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Caches have lots of different properties depending on requirements.  I'm not sure where to start, the question is very open ended.  Look at HashMap, I guess.

Comment: In java there are lots of meanings for cache depends on the type of application you are using whether Standalone or Web App. Update your question with that first and then you can fit in any of the different solutions given below otherwise your question will be marked off topic

Answer (score 0):

Try to store to in a `HashMap` with key `data` and value the created class. If the method is called first check if a class with this type is already in the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Create the objects in constructor and store them in private variables

```
private AppObject appObject;
private TestObject testObject;

public MyConstructor() {
    this.appObject = new AppObject();
    this.testObject = new TestObject();
}

public MyInterface createObject(EnumData data){
 //creates many objects of the classes implements MyInterface interface
 switch(data)
 {
     case AppObject:
         return this.appObject;
     case TestObject:
         return this.testObject
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to create an object once, and return it each time createObject is called, you should just create a field in the same class createObject exists in:

```
private AppObject yourAppObject = new AppObject();
private TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
```

Then createObject could look like so:

```
public MyInterface createObject(EnumData data){
//creates many objects of the classes implements MyInterface interface
    switch(data)
    {
        case AppObject:
            return yourAppObject();
        case TestObject:
            return yourTestObject();
    }
}
```

Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the same objects for the life of the application:

```
enum EnumData {
    APP_OBJECT(new AppObject()), TEST_OBJECT(new TestObject());

    private final MyInterface obj;

    private EnumData(final MyInterface obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public MyInterface getObject() {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public MyInterface createObject(final EnumData data){
    return data.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this, the simplest being that you define a class field that contains your instance.

Another way is to create an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) that creates and caches your instances.